# Bootstrap navbar button height and width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am pretty new to bootstrap am reading the site and making some examples. I started with navbar. When I make a link it appears as a button in navbar but its height and width are showing weirdly. Here is my snippet:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
            id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Portal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Portal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Members</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Login</a></li>
                <!-- here is the problem -->
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Register</a></li>
                <!-- here is the problem -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks.

[Screenshot http://s10.postimg.org/n8ozhzd9j/bootstrap_button.png](http://s10.postimg.org/n8ozhzd9j/bootstrap_button.png)

Comment: Can you post a screen shot to help us quantify "weird"?

Comment: @BrianBolli added screeshot link

Comment: You'll need to move the buttons outside the `navbar-nav` and add the `navbar-btn` class to them. Might want to put them inside a `<div class="navbar-right">`

Comment: What cvrebert wrote is correct

Comment: @cvrebert i pulled them out of navbar-nav and placed inside div as you suggested added a class with margin-top:8px; fix styling. when i resize the window just before mobile view buttons are floating below the search box.

Comment: That's probably due to the floats involved in navbar-left/right.